# PHP Multiple cURL requests, best performance suggestions?

Tags: php, performance, curl, query-performance, php-curl

I'm rusty on PHP and programming after taking a long break, but currently building my own tool for some business needs.

Have a basic landing page setup with a form, which collects lead info (name, phone, address, email, etc).

The form inputs that get submitted are saved to our database (using PHP) and we then post a cURL request to make an API call to a web service to which we also send this data to.

Noticing about 35% of our leads saved in the database aren't showing up in this web service for some reason. Went through several leads in the DB and made an API curl request individually one by one, and most of the ones missing went through successfully this time, so it's not a problem with the data itself.

I'm thinking it has to do with the script we have connected to our landing page form and performance issues. Have been reading up on curl_multi_exec: https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/

However, will that really help? Because each form submission is made separately so these requests are all happening in separate threads.

Or should best practice be to *not* make the API request after each individual form submission, instead set a cron job every 2-3 hours to collect leads in the past hour and do a batch API request on them then?

Also is it true that since each form submission and curl request is separate, `curl_close($curl);` should not be added at the end?

Have something really simple like this at the moment:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://APIURL/{$data}",
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xml
]);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: you're probably missing error checks somewhere, you need to find out why some records don't go through. did you know that curl_setopt() returns bool(false) if there was a problem setting an option? is your code verifying that your curl_setopt calls actually return bool(true)? is your code generating an error report whenever your curl_setopt() calls does not return bool(true) ? same question for curl_exec